# Function to get information from data

Tags: php

I have information on some items:

Actually i have this array:

```
$datas = array(
    array(
        'name'            => "Banana", 
        'color'           => "yellow",
        'scientificName'  => "Banana",
        'weight'          => "300",
        'quantity'        => "3500",
        'origin'          => "Africa"
    ),
    array (...)
);
```

I will need to call this function/array like this:

**Example 1**

```
// echo getDatas($what_I_know, "what_I_want");
// Must return yellow.
echo getDatas("Banana", "color");
```

**Example 2**

```
// echo getDatas($what_I_know, "what_I_want");
// Must return 3500.
echo getDatas("yellow", "quantity");
```

All the keys and data will be unique.

**Question**

How can I proceed?

Comment: Have you written any PHP code yet? There is no indication of what format your information is in -- is it an array?

Comment: I actually have an array but the structure is not the best to make this job...

Comment: Please post your array as part of the question -- otherwise it's difficult to know what to advise.

Comment: I have update the code with the array.

Comment: So, `foreach` over it, check `name`. If matches - return the requested value

Comment: For the first example yes. But for the second, it's not name, it's color.

Comment: My example is just an example... My values are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this:

```
# parameters: $datas array, the value you've got, the value you want to find
function getData($datas, $got, $to_find) {
    foreach ($datas as $d) {
        # check if the value exists in the array
        if (array_search($got, $d)) {
            # it does! Make sure the property we want is also there
            if (in_array($to_find, array_keys($d))) {
                return $d[$to_find];
            }
            else {
                return "No value exists for $to_find";
            }
        }
    }
    return "No data found for $got.";
}


$datas = array(
    array(
        'name'            => "Banana", 
        'color'           => "yellow",
        'scientificName'  => "Banana",
        'weight'          => "300",
        'quantity'        => "3500",
        'origin'          => "Africa"
    ),
    array (
        'name'            => "Apple", 
        'color'           => "red",
        'scientificName'  => "Apple",
        'weight'          => "100",
        'quantity'        => "200",
        'origin'          => "England"

    )
);
echo getData($datas, "Banana", "color") . PHP_EOL;
echo getData($datas, "yellow", "quantity") . PHP_EOL;
echo getData($datas, "red", "weight") . PHP_EOL;
echo getData($datas, "Mongoose", "origin") . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
yellow
3500
100
No data found for Mongoose.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but should work.

```
foreach( $datas as $dat ) {
    foreach( $dat as $k => $d ) {
        if ( $what_i_know == $d ) {
            return $dat[$what_i_want];
        }
    }
}
```